# Complexity of a basic algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I have this example algorithm:

```
int sum = 0;
int j = 1;
while (j <= n) {
    sum++;
    j = j * 2;
}
```

The book I am reading, "Building Java Programs - a Back to the Basics Approach" tells me that I need to find this:

Approximate the runtime of the following code fragment, in terms of n: Write your answer in a format such as `O(N^2)` or `O(N log N)`.

I don't seem to understand how to get from point a to point b here. I figured two statements = `O(2)`, and a loop with two statements = `O(2N)` so it should be `O(2N + 2)`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big-O value for iteration sof a while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26052207/big-o-value-for-iteration-sof-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When determining complexities, we don't include constants or coefficients. Instead of O(2N + 2), it should be O(n). We only care about numbers if they're exponential, i.e. 2^n or n^2, log2(n), etc.

Putting that aside, are you sure this is O(n)? O(n) would mean that it runs `n` times, but it looks like `j` is going to catch up to `n` before `n` times. See what I'm saying?

EDIT: Ok, here's what's going on.

Look what happens with `j`. `j = j * 2`. `j` is doubling every time. In other words, the difference between `j` and `n` is being *halved*. When the number of iterations remaining is halved on every iteration, that's called a log(n) algorithm. log(n) algorithms are pretty awesome because even if `n` is extremely large, log(n) is surprisingly small. Plug some numbers in to see what I mean.

Comment: @Andrew Well look at how fast `j` is growing each time. How would you describe it in English? Once you know that, you should be able to figure out how to write it in Big O, either by having learnt it in the book or googling. Or asking us :)

Comment: @Andrew figure it out yet? Let me know if you're having difficulty.

Comment: Yeah I havn't figured it out and I've been trying for hours. I'm using an online thing called "Practice-it" but it doesn't give feedback, only right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The loop does not iterate through every value from 1 to N, which is where your O(2N) is going wrong.

It might help to visualize the runtime if you substitute the program with the following, which will have the same complexity - this is similar to algorithms that halve the input size on each iteration

```
int j = n;
while(j > 1) {
  j = j / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to determine the complexity, you are on the right track with trying to find the number of operations! What I usually do if I can't pull up the formula immediately: I find examples first. Try it out for n = 5, n = 8,  n=64, n=65 and come up with the number of steps taken, and you'll see soon the pattern!

The formula for number of operations you'll come up with can be very precise, but you can leave the constants out to determine the order of complexity (multipliers and additional constants), as in the end O(2n) is roughly the same as O(3n)compared to O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks to *approximate* the time, an exact time or formula is not required.

Also, Big O Notation, e.g. O(N), tends to be *simplified to the most dominant term only* (i.e. the term of N whereby if N is very large, that term alone would provide an exact or nearly exact answer).

So, if your exact formula were, say, **4N^2 + 9N + 7**, your answer would be **O(N^2)**. Because if N was very large, the N^2 term alone would be enough to approximate the answer.

Also, yts has a point about the j variable, as it's changing exponentially, so from your code the time, t will be:

*t = 2(sum) + 2 = 2(log2(n)+1) + 2*

Therefore your solution is maybe, of the form **O(log N)**, or perhaps **O(log2 N)**?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say break it down; this sort of problem looks deceptively straightforward at once, but proving it out would be valuable.

Let's assume n = 100.

- First iteration:  `sum = 1, j = 2`
- Second iteration:  `sum = 2, j = 4`
- Third iteration: `sum = 3, j = 8`
- Fourth iteration: `sum = 4, j = 16`
- Fifth iteration:  `sum = 5, j = 32`
- Sixth iteration:  `sum = 6, j = 64`
- Seventh iteration: `sum = 7, j = 128` # end of iterations.

If this ran in O(N) time, then you would expect about a hundred iterations.  We instead increase `j` by a factor of 2 every time instead, reaching the terminal iteration after about seven times.

That said, we iterate at least once (for n > 1), plus the floor of `log(100)/log(2) = 6`, for a total of 7 times.

I am inclined to believe that, based on running this little test, that the runtime of this is **O(log(n))**, and not O(n).

Recall from [this graph](http://bigocheatsheet.com/#chart); logarithms grow much slower over time given large values of N.  Even with n = 1000, you would only see 10 iterations.